# Finding Database Default Locations

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore

I am working on creating a script to restore database from a backup file to default location of an instance, which is set away from system databases installation folder.

Currently, I'm using to find default `DATA` Location

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(physical_name, 1, CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf', LOWER(physical_name)) - 1)
    FROM master.sys.master_files
    WHERE database_id = 1 AND file_id = 1
```

and default `LOG` Location

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(physical_name, 1, CHARINDEX(N'mastlog.ldf', LOWER(physical_name)) - 1)
    FROM master.sys.master_files
    WHERE database_id = 1
        AND file_id = 2
    )
```

Is there any other way to find database default location with the help of query?

Thank you for time.

Comment: FYI only ... For SQL Server 2012 and up, *undocumented* `SERVERPROPERTY('INSTANCEDEFAULTDATAPATH')` and `SERVERPROPERTY('INSTANCEDEFAULTLOGPATH')` can be looked into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current method won't work, because it assumes that `master` was placed in the default data/log path, that it hasn't been moved at any point, and that the defaults haven't been changed since then.

The registry approaches work, but they are kind of tedious (especially if you don't use the instance-specific XPs and have to provide the registry path yourself), and who knows if this is where the locations will always be stored.

A different approach - assuming model doesn't have ridiculous file size settings - is to just create a database temporarily and see where SQL Server puts it by default.

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE [!#floobernuggets];
GO
SELECT 
  [type] = CASE [type] WHEN 1 THEN 'data' ELSE 'log' END,
  [path] = SUBSTRING(physical_name, 1, 
    CHARINDEX(N'!#floobernuggets', physical_name)-1)
  FROM sys.master_files
  WHERE database_id = DB_ID(N'!#floobernuggets')
  ORDER BY [type];
GO
DROP DATABASE [!#floobernuggets];
GO
```

(This also assumes your default path doesn't actually contain the string `!#floobernuggets` already, and that you don't have any weird alerts or anything triggered off the actual creation of a database.)

Of course as Kin points out [in SQL Server 2012 you will be able to use `SERVERPROPERTY`](http://sqlandme.com/2013/05/06/sql-server-how-to-find-default-data-and-log-path-for-sql-server-2012/) for this.

```
SELECT [data] = SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath'), 
       [log]  = SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. Your provided method worked best.

Answer (score 5):

Most SQL Servers are configured for the non-system databases to exist apart from the system databases.  That is what is normally meant by the *default path*.

You can lookup some code for finding this at:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/684020/Checking-MS-SQL-Server-database-files-default-path

Also, Alex Aza has provided a popular post over at StackOverflow. The key is to get the data from the registry keys where they are stored.  Here is a snippet from Alex's longer script:

```
declare @DefaultData nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
   N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', 
   N'DefaultData', @DefaultData output

declare @DefaultLog nvarchar(512)
exec master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
   N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', 
   N'DefaultLog', @DefaultLog output
```

Answer (score 4):

You won't want to use this method as the location of the master database files won't necessarily indicate the default location. I specify my master databases files to be on a separate drive, for example, while all the user databases are defaulted to another.

You can use the following query from  [SQLandMe](http://sqlandme.com/tag/xp_instance_regread/) to find the default database locations:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempInstanceNames
 (
  InstanceName      NVARCHAR(100),
  RegPath           NVARCHAR(100),
  DefaultPath   NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )

INSERT INTO #tempInstanceNames (InstanceName, RegPath)
EXEC   master..xp_instance_regenumvalues
   @rootkey = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
   @key     = N'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Instance Names\\SQL'

DECLARE     @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET         @SQL = 'DECLARE @returnValue NVARCHAR(100)'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) +
'EXEC   master.dbo.xp_regread
@rootkey      = N''HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'',
@key          = N''SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\' + RegPath + '\MSSQLServer'',
@value_name   = N''DefaultData'',
@value        = @returnValue OUTPUT;

UPDATE #tempInstanceNames SET DefaultPath = @returnValue
WHERE RegPath = ''' + RegPath + '''' + CHAR(13) FROM #tempInstanceNames

EXEC (@SQL)

SELECT      InstanceName, RegPath, DefaultPath
FROM        #tempInstanceNames
```

and the following for log locations:

```
DECLARE     @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET         @SQL = 'DECLARE @returnValue NVARCHAR(100)'
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) +
'EXEC   master.dbo.xp_regread
@rootkey      = N''HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'',
@key          = N''SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\' + RegPath + '\MSSQLServer'',
@value_name   = N''DefaultLog'',
@value        = @returnValue OUTPUT;

UPDATE #tempInstanceNames SET DefaultPath = @returnValue
WHERE RegPath = ''' + RegPath + '''' + CHAR(13) FROM #tempInstanceNames

EXEC (@SQL)

SELECT      InstanceName, RegPath, DefaultPath
FROM        #tempInstanceNames
```